# Android Layout land not working

Tags: android, layout, onconfigurationchanged, android-configchanges

I've been looking at issues in stackoverflow and I've tried everything I've seen but the layout-land not work.
In my code I have and the method `onConfigurationChanged`

```
@Override
 public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);           
}
```

And the manifest file:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.sde.PlayerTrack"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        >
    </activity>
```

I tried also to remove in the android manifest entry: configChanges and then the layout land         load but the components i have (TextView, scrollbar ...) does not work properly.

Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally, my solution is:

AndroidManifest.xml File:

```
<activity
        android:name="activity.name"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"       
        >
```

And in the activity implement the method onConfigurationChanged (Configuration newconfig):

```
@Override
 public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);     
        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            createHorizontalalLayout();            
        } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
            createVerticalLayout();             
        }
}
```

With createVerticalLayout () and createHorizontalLayout () programmatically do the layouts.

Answer (score 27):

Remove `orientation` from the `android:configChanges` in your manifest file, and put you landscape layout **xml** file into `layout-land` folder.

Comment: I already did that before and it works but I have progressbar not working properly. Thanks.

Comment: what exactly problem you are facing with progressbar, Can you explain in detail?

Comment: I have an asynchronous class that loads a song just start the activity. Then when the screen rotates the land layout works but the song is not continuous but is reloaded.

Comment: This way will do reload data. Not good.  
I want when rotate screen, no reload data, which only auto select layout in layout-land or layout-port folder.  
Please help me.

Comment: Mistakenly left configChanges in manifest. Can't thank you enough for this answer. Was just about to give up.

Answer (score 3):

For me the missing piece was clean build. Somehow my changes were not reflecting.
Here are the steps that I performed.

1. creating a **layout-land** folder parallel to the **layout** folder.
2. copying activity_main.xml to layout-land folder and modifying activity_main.xml for a landscape layout.
3. **It is important that you are able to preview both layouts in the design view. When you go to the design view of the layout file,  you see a mobile rotate type of icon. You should be able to switch between layout previews using that icon. If you are able to switch that means your folder structure is correct. You can even do step 1 and step 2 using this.
   Make sure that you Fix layout errors.**
4. Your AndroidManifest.xml should not have "orientation" item in attribute android:configChanges=""

For me it is empty as of now

```
<activity android:name="com.sudoxer.app.MainActivity" android:configChanges="">
```

5. Clean the project and rebuild it after this change.

You should see what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Check emulator if you are running Android Emulator 4.4 it has some kind of bug in it's orientation. I had the same problem changed my emulator to 4.0.3 and everything worked fine. Visit here for more details [site](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61671)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and after much debugging found the culprit in the build.gradle file.  Android studio had added the line

```
sourceSets { main { res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res', 'src/main/res/layout-land'] } }
```

while I was messing around trying to create layout-land manually.  I removed that line and normal function returned.